# Spring Boot CommandLineRunner and constructor injection

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired, constructor-injection

I'm learning about Spring Boot CommandLineRunner. And I have this code:

```
@Component
public class DataLoader implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final OwnerService ownerService;
    private final VetService vetService;

    public DataLoader() {
        ownerService = new OwnerServiceMap();
        vetService = new VetServiceMap();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    ...
    }
```

When is this constructor called? I want to know if this is a constructor injection or not? I see there is no @Autowired but I know that it isn't mandatory to put @Autowired when there is only one constructor. Any feedback will be apreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yes the default constructor will be called, but this is *not* constructor injection - you have nothing to inject in that constructor to begin with.

That constructor will be called at Spring initiation time, when all the beans are being build and placed into application context.

And since you are doing `new OwnerServiceMap()/new VetServiceMap()` (using the `new` operator) you are bypassing Spring's proxy - thus those if they have some annotations like `@Transactional` let's suppose, will not work.

Comment: Maybe one additional thing for the "When is this constructor called?" question. The constructor will be called at spring boot start. (Default every component is a singleton)